# SQL compare datetime column with specific hour and minute time range

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, if-statement, case

I need write a `CASE` statement like below;

`Datetime` column: `'2020-04-09 08:34:00.000'`

I don't care year,month,day parts. Just want to compare hour and minutes part with specific hour and minute.

If `hh:mm` parts of `datetime` value between `'05:30'` and `'15:30'` Then 1

If `hh:mm` parts of `datetime` value between `'15:31'` and `'05:29'` Then 2

How can i achieve this?

Comment: `CONVERT`/`CAST` and the `time` data type appear to be appropriate here. What have *you* tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved myself i think;

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME

SET @StartDate = '2020-04-09 16:30:00.000'

Select CASE WHEN CAST(CAST(DATEPART(HH,@StartDate)as varchar)+':'+CAST(DATEPART(mi,@StartDate)as varchar)+':'+CAST(DATEPART(ss,@StartDate) as varchar) as time(0)) between CAST('05:30:00' AS time(0)) and CAST('15:29:59' AS time(0)) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
SELECT
   CASE   
      WHEN CONVERT(TIME, YourDateTime) >= '05:30:00' AND CONVERT(TIME, YourDateTime) < '15:30:00' THEN 1   
      WHEN CONVERT(TIME, YourDateTime) >= '15:30:00' OR CONVERT(TIME, YourDateTime) < '05:30:00' THEN 2      
   END ColumnName
FROM XYZ_TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

The following usage will return the time and hour

```
  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),getdate(),108)  AS HourMinute

+------------+
| HourMinute |
+------------+
| 12:33      |
+------------+
```

So, you can use the following CASE implementation:

**EDITED:**

```
   SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),YourDateTime,108) ,
   CASE   
      WHEN CONVERT(time,YourDateTime,108)  >=  '05:30' AND  CONVERT(time,YourDateTime,108) < '15:30' THEN 1   
       WHEN CONVERT(time,YourDateTime,108)  >=  '15:30' OR  CONVERT(time,YourDateTime,108) < '05:30' THEN 2   
   END CaseResult
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: I not working in 24 hour format. When i send '2020-04-09 16:30:00.000' it return null.

Comment: It has been fixed

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple query as

```
select *, case when v >= '08:30' and v <= '15:30' then 1 else 2 end
from
(
  values
  (cast('2020-04-09 08:34:00' as time))
) t(v)
```